# How can I get the `bcmath` plugin in php5 in Ubuntu?

Tags: php

I've seen a PHP [BC-MATH](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) installation for `YUM` but not `apt-get`. Does one know of a working `apt-get` solution?

Unfortunately, from this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217871/enable-bcmath-using-php-ini), `apt-get install php5-bcmath` gives the error `Unable to locate package php5-bcmath`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`php5-fpm` in Precise and later (as well as the Apache equivalent `libapache2-mod-php5` package for Apache built-in PHP5 modules) is listed as having `bcmath` built in to it as an included module.  This information is written in the package description file (`debian/control`) in the package itself when extracted and being viewed as the raw source package, containing source code and a `debian/` directory which contains directives to debian build systems to build packages.

Given that the `php5-fpm` system as well as the `libapache2-mod-php5` plugin for Apache has it included by default, I don't think you have to install any additional packages or plugins to get `bcmath`.

---

In case my word isn't enough and you want to see the evidence of this, then...

This is a list of links to the `debian/rules` file which defines which extensions are enabled in PHP at the time of building for each currently supported release at the time of this post (there may be updates after this post that are not reflected here).  You can click each of these to see the `./configure` arguments that are passed to `php5` during the building process for those packages.  Note that this will show you specifically where `bcmath` is enabled for all `php5` binaries in those releases:

- [`debian/control` file for `php5` in Precise](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/precise/php5/precise-security/view/head:/debian/rules#L134)
- [`debian/control` file for `php5` in Quantal](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/quantal/php5/quantal-security/view/head:/debian/rules#L134)
- [`debian/control` file for `php5` in Saucy](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/saucy/php5/saucy/view/head:/debian/rules#L128)
- [`debian/control` file for `php5` in Trusty](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/php5/trusty/view/head:/debian/rules#L121)

Answer (score 20):

If you use Ondřej Surý's [PHP PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) you can install `bcmath` with either

```
sudo apt install php5.6-bcmath
sudo apt install php7.0-bcmath
sudo apt install php-bcmath
```

There are instructions on the PPA page on how to add this source to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to install bcmath extension, Please try below commands :

For PHP5.6

```
sudo apt install php5.6-bcmath
```

For PHP7.0

```
sudo apt install php7.0-bcmath
```

For other PHP versions

```
sudo apt install php-bcmath
```

Comment: I found that `sudo apt install php-bcmath` worked on PHP7.0 too (it automatically gets the 7.0 one) and if you do that then it likely works better when you later upgrade PHP.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install php5.5-bcmath
```

worked for me.

Comment: At least on 16.04 this package doesn't exist in the default sources. What exists is `php-bcmath`

Comment: For 16.04 I used `sudo apt-get install php7.0-bcmath' and it worked. I'm presuming it will work for any given version of php (though I haven't tested).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Docker run this command in your PHP container shell:

```shell
docker-php-ext-install bcmath
```

Or add this line in your `Dockerfile`:

```shell
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath
```